# multibyte libs in unicode exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, character-encoding, mfc

I am using a library which is compiled in visual studio using the multibyte character set option.

The library is being used in a MFC project which is using the Unicode character set.

At compile and link time I am not running into any issues.

Are there any runtime "gotchas" that I shoushould aware of?

Comment: Problem not clearly stated. Please add more details, and actual issue

Comment: There no known specific problem. That's what the question states. I want to know if there is any behaviour/problems I should be aware of. I have found little documentation to assist my own research into this topic.